# python3 gspread exception not caught

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

I have the following piece of code which attempts to capture a gspread.exceptions.APIError, usually as the result of a timeout of the Google spreadsheet credentials. _open_sheet requests a new set of credentials.

```
def _findRow(self, entry):
''' Return row index for row which contains "entry". '''
for i in range(10):
    try:
        cell = self.worksheet.find(email)
        return cell.row
    except gspread.exceptions.CellNotFound:
        return None
    except gspread.exceptions.APIError:
        # This occurs when we get a timeout of the authentication token
        # Need to reauthenticate
        self._open_sheet()
        continue
print('Leadsheet:find:: Failed to renew authorization after 10 attempts.')
return None
```

and from the following stack trace the gspread.exceptions.APIError is not caught:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app 
    response = self.full_dispatch_request() 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request 
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception 
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise 
    raise value 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request 
    rv = self.dispatch_request() 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request 
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) 
  File "/app/app/api_1_0/views.py", line 79, in lead 
    statSheet.updateStats(config.leadsheetTile) 
  File "/app/app/statSheet.py", line 71, in updateStats 
    row = self._findRow(entry) 
  File "/app/app/statSheet.py", line 54, in _findRow 
    cell = self.worksheet.find(entry) 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 805, in find 
    return self._finder(finditem, query) 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 779, in _finder 
    data = self.spreadsheet.values_get(self.title) 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 110, in values_get 
    r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params) 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 79, in request 
    raise APIError(response) 
gspread.exceptions.APIError: { 
  "error": { 
    "code": 401, 
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", 
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" 
  } 
}
```

Any clues as to what has gone on with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and what worked was:

```
except gspread.CellNotFound:
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happens with me wile I'm writing the data in excel sheet after some period of time this error appears. 
Once I run my script again it works fine but fails after some time.

One thing that observed was while writing data if it reaches the end of the row in that sheet and there is no further row to write then it starts to throw such error.

So you need to catch this exception as below:

```
    try:
        Sheet.update_cell(row, column, value="What ever value")t_term)
    except gspread.exceptions.APIError as UNAUTHENTICATED:
        print("Api error occurred for gspread due to authentication failure while writing What ever value.")
```